# Concept of integration

Tags: integration

Can I say "I integrate over points and reach to a curve" like I say "I integrate over infinitesimally small segments and reach to a curve"? I mean, is integration definable for points, or just infinitesimally small parts of a whole?
Sorry if not clear.

Comment: Neither of those two sentences seem to be in standard English. What the deuce does "reach to a curve" even mean?

Comment: @HenningMakholm If I "decipher" his question correctly, I believe he is wondering whether Riemann Integral can be defined over a discrete set.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I'm sorry, English is not my mother language.

Comment: Suppose I show time on an axis. Then any time interval is a segment on this axis. Any segment consists of infinite number of points. Can I integrate over those "points"? When integrating there is always a dt, dx or something. Yet dt is an infinitesimally small interval itself, not a single point.

Comment: An integral can be seen as an area so it is more intuitive to say that you are decomposing the surface in rectangles or trapezoids having an edge that follows the curve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure whether this answers your question since it is stated in a rather problematic manner, but I guess you are  wondering whether the Riemann Integral is defined over discrete sets. Try checking the definition of a Riemann sum to see where that leads:

In general, if $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\Bbb{R}$ and $$P=[a=x_0<x_1<...<x_n=b]\\E_p={ξ_1,ξ_2,...,ξ_n}\\ ξ_k \in[x_{k-1},x_k], (1\le k\le n)$$ you have:$$R(f,P,E_p)=\sum_{k=1}^nf(ξ_k)(x_k-x_{k-1})$$
And$$\int_a^bf=\lim_{||P||\rightarrow0} R(f,P,E_p)= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}R(f,P_n,E_{p_{n}}) $$

If you had a discrete set, say $f:[x_0,x_1,...,x_n]\rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ defined over as you said "single points", instead of "infitensimally parts of the whole", you would end up adding zeros. 

Indeed, since $(x_k-x_{k-1})=0$, you get $$\sum_{k=1}^nf(ξ_k)(x_k-x_{k-1})=0$$
which is also in accordance with the intuitive notion of integral as an area (the rectangles involved in the sum, all have zero area: $f(x_k)(x_k-x_{k-1})=0$).

**EDIT**: To answer more strictly regarding whether a function such as the one you describe is Riemann integrable we can use the fact that:

A Riemann Integrable function is almost everywhere continuous.

A function that is defined only at discrete points is nowhere continuous. It's graph is basically a scatter plot and by that you can also intuitively see why the areas of the rectangles that "normally" appear are all zero. But it is Lebesgue integrable and it's integral is equal to zero. You can see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1379610/can-someone-help-me-understand-this-integrating-over-a-discrete-set-of-points-y).

Comment: There seems no problem to this proof, but then doesn't that violate the definition of a one-dimensional thing such as a segment consisting of infinite number of single points?

Comment: @Simorq It's not really a proof, more of an incentive/guideline to look at the subject more closely I would say. As for what you are asking now, I fear I am not sure about this definition and it's relevance to the problem.

Comment: 1.Why not a proof? 2. According to what you've shown here, any path I choose, integrating over discrete sets (single points) yields zero. Can I not thus conclude that Riemann integral is not definable over discrete sets?

Comment: @Simorq Check the edit above-I hope it makes it clearer!